# combine date ranges in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, datetime

I have 2 lists with lists of date ranges. `dates1` and `dates2`.
I would like to combine the first list of `date1` with the first list of `date2`

When I try to to add the lists to each other I get the following error:
`TypeError: cannot add DatetimeArray and DatetimeArray`

This is what they look like if I print them:

```
for i,j in zip(dates1, dates2):
    print(i, j)

DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-16 18:00:00', '2016-01-16 19:00:00',
               '2016-01-16 20:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H') DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-16 21:00:00', '2016-01-16 22:00:00',
               '2016-01-16 23:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H')
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-23 17:45:00', '2016-01-23 18:45:00',
               '2016-01-23 19:45:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H') DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-23 20:30:00', '2016-01-23 21:30:00',
               '2016-01-23 22:30:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H')
```

So basically I want to have the first 3 timestamps and the following 3 timestamps together in a list and so on.
How do I make sure I can add these date ranges to each other? Help would be appreciated!

(It is specifically about the separate timestamps it does not necessarily have to be a range)

Comment: do you need `join` or `merge`?

Comment: what do you mean by "combine"? you certainly would not want to *add* them (what is date1 + date2 supposed to mean?)

Comment: the [union](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) method might be interesting

Comment: @MrFuppes Thanks! The union method was exactly what I needed